# Difference between array.count and array.size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Is there any difference between `array.count` and `array.size`?

I am getting errors sometimes on production environment while using `array.count`, but the same works fine when I use `array.size`.

Comment: There was a good post about this a few years back: blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/2/27/count-length-size

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Starting from Ruby 1.8.7, `Array#count` is the same of `Array#size`.

Please note that `Array#count` doesn't exist in Ruby versions lower than 1.8.7 so if you are running Ruby 1.8.6 in production, it will raise a `NoMethodError`.

Also, make sure you are talking about arrays. In ActiveRecord, for example, `#size` and `#count` are slightly different. `#size` understands caching like counter cache, while count doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for that. Now only i realized my development system has ruby 1.8.7 and staging had 1.8.6.